# SSRS Calculated Field used in multiple Reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working in Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

A really long Expression [60-70 IIF's] is in a calculated field that is used in about 35 Reports. The Calculated Field expression matches a value from the Data Row [coming in from T_SQL] and designates a 'Group Name' for the row.

Example Data:

```
ID     Prod_Num     Amount
1       123           15
2       234           20
3       345           25
```

Example Expression (pseudo code):

```
IIF (Prod_Num = '123', 'Shirts',
IIF Prod_Num = '234', 'Pants',
IIF Prod_Num = '345', 'Socks', 'Other')
```

Problem is when the Prod_Num list is added to or modified - the changes have to be made in all reports.

What would be a good way to have all this in one place - so that when there are changes, they only need to be made in that one place.

I don't have Create Table rights on the DB and I don't know if that is even an option - though if I DID have the rights, I would put all the Prod_Nums and Categories (Shirts . . . Pants . . .) into a Table and then just do the work in the SQL for the report.

I thought of a T_SQL Function but some of the Reports use a Linked Server to pull data from a Progress DB . . . and I don't know how that would work with a SQL Server Function??

I'd appreciate any help/suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the right approach is create a table for mapping prod_num and categories. Otherwise if you hardcode the mapping either in T-SQL or SSRS it will be a pain to maintain every time a new product is added to your database.

Comment: Yeah as a general rule i tell people, do as little logic as possible in SSRS, do it all in a SPROC that is the data set for the SSRS. Way easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your expression into a function in a [Custom Code Assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159238(v=sql.105).aspx) in SSRS.

Then you add that assembly to all the reports that need it, and all you have to do on each report is call that function in an expression.

By the way, you should be using Visual Studio 2008 to build reports for SSRS 2008R2.  Reports built in VS2013 are not guaranteed to work on SSRS 2008R2.

Comment: Thanks! I will look at the Custom Code Assembly suggestion. Our Reports work fine. We are even working with VS 2008 reports IN VS 2013 and negligible issues. We have SOME performance issues but we believe those are related to our used of a linked server and 'openquery' . . . as well as SQL that pulls a lot more fields than are required [I suspect because of 'borrowing' SQL from other reports to use as  templates].

Answer (score 0):

You will have the same issue wherever you place this logic if you are not enforcing the relationship in your data, i.e. creating a type table for your products.

The only leverage you can gain is to move the hardcodes from many locations to just one so that when you do update a table(s), you can **clearly document** one other location that must also be updated. Here are a few examples :

1. As [Tab Allerman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1507566/tab-alleman) pointed out, create a class function inside an assembly and embed that assembly into each report. You then just update the server with a new assembly when your choices change.
2. Create a custom SP in a database that every report will have access to, even if it is not your report's main database. (You can create multiple data sources in a report.)
3. Use a  web service as a data source for your reports and put the types in one location this way.
4. Use an xml document as a data source for your reports and put the types in one location this way.
5. Ask the person(s) maintaining the database why the heck the products are not typified.

Comment: First of all . . . LOL on your last comment, "why the heck . . .". That was actually the FIRST question I asked when I first came to this job - but the DBAs are in a whole other stratosphere. I am still hopeful that this can get done. Meanwhile I will have to explore some of your other suggestions. Thanks!